# Getting the root reducer from configureStore redux toolkit

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, redux, redux-toolkit

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import testSlice from "./testSlice";
import {combineReducers} from "redux";

const rootReducer = combineReducers({test: testSlice})
export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer,
});

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof rootReducer>
```

This is my current workaround in order to get the type of my root reducer. I'm reading the docs and I can't seem to find how to get my root reducer from the store if I was using slices to create the reducer in my configure store. It's just disappointing that I have to use combineReducers again while using redux-toolkit just to get my rootReducer type.

I'm looking for a code like this:

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import testSlice from "./testSlice";
import userSlice from "./userSlice";

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {test: testSlice, user: userSlice},
});

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getReducer()>
```

Answer (score 2):

A better type for RootState would be as below:

```
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>
```

This implementation is included in the [document](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/tutorials/typescript#define-root-state-and-dispatch-types). Please take time to read it.

If your intention of getting the rootReducer isn't only for defining the RootState type, you can simply named-export it from store file and then import it in your desired file to use.

```js
// store.js
// ...
export const rootReducer = combineReducers({test: testSlice});
```

It's not a common and practical usage for the rootReducer to be imported and consumed in other places but the store file, where it will be used to configure the store object.
Therefore, I think there's no point for Redux Toolkit to provide a way to access the rootReducer.

Answer (score 1):

#### You don't need to

[Huan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69149714/10431574) is spot-on.  It is very unlikely that you will actually need to access the root reducer type.  You can get the state type without it.  Their answer is the best solution to underlying problem.

#### But if you want to...

If anyone reading this question would like to know how to derive the root reducer type from the store type, it *can* be done by using TypeScript conditional types.  This is the same sort of logic that you see in the [redux source code](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/d794c56f78eccb56ba3c67971c26df8ee34dacc1/src/types/reducers.ts).

We can define a reusable utility type that gets the reducer type from the type of the store.  It does this by accessing the types for the state `S` and the action `A`, which are both generic type parameters of the redux `Store<S, A>` type.  Then we apply those same generics to the `Reducer<S, A>` type.

```
// Can be imported from 'redux' or from '@reduxjs/toolkit', both are the same.
import { Reducer, Store } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

type ReducerFromStore<T> = T extends Store<infer S, infer A> ? Reducer<S, A> : never
```

You can use this utility type to get the root reducer type from a specific store instance.

```
export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {test: testSlice, user: userSlice},
});

export type RootReducer = ReducerFromStore<typeof store>;
```

Note: The exact type of the `store` object created by `configureStore` is the redux toolkit [`EnhancedStore` type](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/blob/8565fc25803beedc1032d67473c6b448da588405/packages/toolkit/src/configureStore.ts#L103).  But this extends the core redux `Store` type, so no special handling is needed.